# How to create tar.gz file in windows by only one step?

Tags: windows, tar, gzip

I know that i can create tar.gz file by 7-zip in two steps. First step for tar format and second for tar.gz format. But is there a way to get tar.gz in only one step ?

Comment: See [How do I use 7-Zip for Windows to create .tar.gz archives?](http://superuser.com/q/339931/57579)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i must rewrite command line every time i want to create tar.gz file. That is not convenient. I want to achieve this by right click like 7-zip originally do.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1283392/12824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into the 7-zip source code, i extended the 7-zip context menu by adding "add to tar.gz" item. and it works !

Comment: you can get the extended 7-zip.dll at [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9opVQm9Lxg4ZlZxQUtPUWJOSEU). Hope it helps!

Comment: on your readme file, you mentioned to restart computer. I think is enough if you kill explorer process and start a new one. Anyway, thanks buddy